# Filtering asp:SqlDataSource by a JOIN Column

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm trying to filter my `SqlDataSource` on a column of a JOIN but I get this error:

> The multi-part identifier "B.Name" could not be bound

`SqlDataSource.SelectCommand`:

```
SELECT MD.MediaDocumentID, MD.Name, B.BrandID, B.Name as BrandName
FROM MediaDocument MD
JOIN Brand B ON B.BrandID = MD.BrandID
WHERE MD.Active = 1
```

In code behind I'm using the method `FilterExpression` like this:

```
sqldatasource.FilterExpression = "(B.Name LIKE '%phone%')";
```

Thank you!

Comment: Try Brandname instead of B.Name

Comment: Doesn't work either